# Bioinformatics filtering/selecting based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, r, bioinformatics, sqldf

Hi i'm trying to select distinct OTUs which posess certain KEGG pathways, and i'm wondering why the following doesn't work or what you'd recommend. I've tried dplyr and using `=`, `!=`, `<>` with no success. Any advice ?

```
Group1<-sqldf("SELECT DISTINCT OTU FROM 'retro.flux.avg.OTU'
WHERE Pathway IN ('ko00362','ko00625','ko00361','ko00623','ko00622','ko00633','ko00642','ko00626','ko00624')")
          AND Pathway IN ('ko02030')")

Group2<-sqldf("SELECT DISTINCT OTU FROM 'retro.flux.avg.OTU'
WHERE Pathway IN ('ko00362','ko00625','ko00361','ko00623','ko00622','ko00633','ko00642','ko00626','ko00624')")
          AND Pathway NOT IN ('ko02030')")

Group3<-sqldf("SELECT DISTINCT OTU FROM 'retro.flux.avg.OTU'
WHERE Pathway NOT IN ('ko00362','ko00625','ko00361','ko00623','ko00622','ko00633','ko00642','ko00626','ko00624')")
          AND Pathway IN ('ko02030')")


Group4<-sqldf("SELECT DISTINCT OTU FROM 'retro.flux.avg.OTU'
WHERE Pathway NOT IN ('ko02030','ko00362','ko00625','ko00361','ko00623','ko00622','ko00633','ko00642','ko00626','ko00624')")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I think

Instead of

```
Group1<-sqldf("SELECT DISTINCT OTU FROM 'retro.flux.avg.OTU'
WHERE Pathway IN ('ko00362','ko00625','ko00361','ko00623','ko00622','ko00633','ko00642','ko00626','ko00624')") 
AND Pathway IN ('ko02030')")
```

just put the following

**removed the extra** `")` and I noticed 1 more bug in query and fixed it

```
Group1<-sqldf("SELECT DISTINCT OTU FROM 'retro.flux.avg.OTU'
WHERE Pathway IN ('ko00362','ko00625','ko00361','ko00623','ko00622','ko00633','ko00642','ko00626','ko00624')")
```